# regex line not containing word?

Tags: regex

I'm hoping that someone can help me with what is possibly a simple regex question.
I need to match lines that contain a set of words, but do not contain another word.

e.g.
The file I am searching contains the following:

> Bob has a hat.
>   Bill has a hat.
>   Fred has a hat.

What I want to do is match all lines that have 'has a hat.' unless the line also contains bob.

Does that make sense ?

This has to be basic regex, not code or anything as I am entering this into a text file parse program.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 7):

```
^(?=.*\bhas a hat\b)(?!.*\bBob\b).*
```

matches an entire line if it  contains `has a hat` anywhere and doesn't contain `Bob` anywhere (in any order).

Of course, it would also not match a line like `Fred has a hat. Bob doesn't`.